# variable already defined error with namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I met ***"already defined error in AppDelegate.obj"*** with C++/cocos2dx.
This is my code in `gamestage.h`

```
#ifndef __GAME_STAGES_H__
#define __GAME_STAGES_H__

// stage 1;
namespace gamestage1
{
    int btn_number = 9;
}

#endif
```

`game.cpp` and `menu.cpp` use this `gamestage.h` file and there are no `gamestage.cpp` file.

Actually, I tried to use `extern` like:

```
extern int btn_number = 9;
```

but It didn't work.

> **What can cause this? **

Comment: Take this to heart: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that contain two underscores (`__GAME_STAGES_H__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved to the implementation. don't use them.

Comment: Note that a declaration that includes an initializer (`extern int btn_number = 9;` is a definition, even if it's marked `extern`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should not define a variable in a header file and include that header in multiple **[translation units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c)**. It breaks the **[One definition rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)** and hence the error.
Remember that the header guards prevents multiple inclusion of the header within the same translation unit not within different translation units.

If you want to share the same global variable across multiple translation units then you need to use `extern`.

**//gameplan.h**

```
// stage 1;
namespace gamestage1
{
    extern int btn_number;
}
```

**//game.cpp**

```
#include "gameplan.h"
namespace gamestage1
{
    int btn_number = 9;
}
```

**//menu.cpp**

```
#include "gameplan.h"
```

Comment: Oh, Thanks for your fast answer. Does it break the one definition rule although I used #ifndef and #define at the top of code?

Comment: @Agora: Updated to answer your question in detail.